# Specify which Chrome to use for ChromeDriver in Rails Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium

In my Rails app I have the following which makes my system tests use ChromeDriver to launch Chrome and perform my tests:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [800, 600]
end
```

However, the Chrome installation I have at `~/Applications/Google Chrome.app` is old and can't be upgraded due to IT restrictions.

Instead what we do is create a folder at:

`~/Users/cameron/Applications (local)/Google Chrome.app` as then we can update the app as we please as we don't have restrictions in place here.

However the ChromeDriver tries to use the version of Chrome in the main `~/Applications` folder instead of my own. How can I tell the Driver to use the one in my local applications folder so that I have the correct version of Chrome running?

As this is causing the error: `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [binary](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object) option (untested):

```
driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [800, 600], options: {
  :binary => 'Path to the Chrome executable'
}
```

Comment: What's the path? If the app is located at: `'~/Users/cameron/Applications (local)/Google Chrome.app'`

Comment: I would try `/Users/cameron/Applications (local)/Google Chrome.app`

Comment: I tried: `'/Users/cameron/Applications (local)/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'` as per the documentation but I get an error: `ArgumentError: unknown option:`

Comment: It's not clear from the doc what `options` should be. I looked into the source code of Capybara  it seems to be equal to `chromeOptions `.

Comment: Still getting the error unknown option. It's like it doesn't understand what `:binary` is.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with this:

<del>driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400], options: { driver_path: 'path/to/chrome' }</del>

I thought I did, but turns out that didn't work either.